# Image not found, serving image placeholder, but what status code do I use?

Tags: http

If I'm handling a request to an image that does not exist and I want to serve a missing image placeholder, what http status code is more appropriate: 302 (moved temporarily) or just 200 (ok)?

Comment: what about 404 not found?